# Inverse of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

Let $b\in(0,1)$ and $c, n$ positive constants. Is it possible to find a function $a(x)$ independent from $b$ such that

$$\int_0^\infty a(x)x^2b^xdx=\frac{c^nb^n}{(c^n-b^n)^2}?$$

Thank you

Comment: You mean that the formula must hold $\forall b \in (0,+\infty)$ ?

Comment: For all $b\in (0,1)$.

Comment: Isn't it then for all $b \in (0,c)$ ?

Comment: Could you tell the origin of the problem ?